# Salesforce Lightning DataTable - field calculations

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I am working on simple lightning data table to show few columns. Users can edit the cell values and it will update corresponding fields based on certain simple calculations. For example, updating Discount would update the Sale Price and vice-versa. Here is the js `handleCellEdit`

```
handleCellEdit(event) {
    let editedRow = event.detail.draftValues[0];
    const fieldName = Object.keys(editedRow)[0];
    const editedValue = editedRow[fieldName];
    const rowId = editedRow.Id;

    // Find the corresponding column in columns attribute based on fieldName
    const column = this.columns.find((col) => col.fieldName === fieldName);

    // Check if the column and data type are valid
    if (column && column.type) {
        // Perform type casting based on the field data type
        switch (column.type) {
            case 'currency':
            case 'number':
            case 'percent':
                editedRow[fieldName] = parseFloat(editedValue || 0); // parseFlot() returns NaN for blank values 
                break;
            case 'date':
                editedRow[fieldName] = new Date(editedValue);
                break;
            default:
                // For other data types, keep the value as-is (assuming they are text fields)
                editedRow[fieldName] = editedValue;
        }
    }

    // Handle field calculations
    const fieldLabel = getFieldLabel(fieldName);

    // Find the corresponding row in tableData
    this.tableData = this.tableData.map((row) => {
        if (row.Id === rowId) {

            editedRow = { ...row, [fieldName]: editedRow[fieldName] };

            if(fieldLabel) {
                switch (fieldLabel) {
                    case 'Discount':
                        return handleDiscount(editedRow, editedValue);
                    case 'SalePrice':
                        return handleSalePrice(editedRow, editedValue);
                    default:
                        return editedRow;
                }
            }

            // Create a new object to represent the updated row
            //return { ...row, [fieldName]: editedRow[fieldName] };
        }

        return row;
    });

    // isTableEdited property is passed to calling component to handle save accordingly  
    this.isTableEdited = true;

    // Emptying draftValues will not show standard save/cancel buttons
    // Not required becuase of suppress-bottom-bar attribute on the datatable
    //this.draftValues = [];
}
```

This are the 2 utility methods

```
export function handleDiscount(row, discount) {

    // Get the actual field API name
    const salePriceFieldName = 'SalePrice';  
    const listPriceFieldName = 'ListPrice';
    
    return {
        ...row,
        [salePriceFieldName]: parseFloat(row[listPriceFieldName] * (1-discount))
    }; 
}

export function handleSalePrice(row, salePrice) {

    // Get the actual field API name
    const discountFieldName = 'Discount';
    const listPriceFieldName = 'ListPrice';
    
    return {
        ...row,
        [discountFieldName]: parseFloat(1-(salePrice / row[listPriceFieldName]))
    };
}
```

The functionality works when updating one field at at time. But not when updating both fields. For example, if List Price is 10, changing Discount to .5, updates the Sale Price to 5. But then when updating the SalePrice to 6, Discount should be updated to .4 (40%), but it still shows .5 (old value)

This seems to be UI only issue. Because I have different component that aggregates the values, and that is working OK. Thank you for any help/pointer

[image]

Update: Clearing the draftValues solves for it. But with that I lose the functionality of knowing which fields were edited.

```
this.draftValues = [];
```